# Update Sqlite Table in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication, registration, sqliteopenhelper

I am getting a error when updating my table...
Error:

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".40609543": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE login SET lname=?,profile_pic=?,email=?,fname=?,mobile=? WHERE uid=5700e194537378.40609543

My SQLiteOpenHelper Class code

```
public void updateProfile(String fname, String lname, String email, String mobile, String profile_pic, String uid) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
    updateValues.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname); // FirstName
    updateValues.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname); // LastName
    updateValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    updateValues.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile); // Mobile Number
    updateValues.put(KEY_PROFILE_PIC, profile_pic);

    db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, updateValues, KEY_UID + "=" + uid, null);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: show your query please. `syntax error`

Comment: whether the type of the id is an integer or some other datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this once.

```
db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, updateValues, KEY_UID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(uid) });
```

Comment: also change textview in fragment when update database ?

Comment: i didn't understand ?

Comment: i am using profile update inside a dialog. when user click save button then change details in main fragment. Name.setText(user.get("fname") + " " + user.get("lname"));
        Mobile.setText(user.get("mobile"));
        Email.setText(user.get("email"));